# displaying other attribute values if one is known in django template

Tags: python, html, django

i have this app in django that i'm trying to make. this is the index.html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Choose the name of student</h1>
    <form action= "{% url 'detail' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
            <select name="namedrop">
                {% for name in student_list %}
                <option value={{name.stuname}}>{{name.stuname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}

            </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the detail.html page to which it is directed when we select a name and click submit button...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Details of student </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello {{name}}</p>

    <style type="text/css">
        p
        {
            color: blue;
        }   

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

but it only shows "hello neha" if the name selected is "neha"... but i want it to print all the details of this student from the table student...this is models.py...

```
from django.db import models

class course(models.Model):
    cid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    cname=models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cname

    class Meta:
        db_table= "course"


class student(models.Model):
    stuid=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stuname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cid=models.ForeignKey(course,to_field='cid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stuname

    class Meta:
        db_table= "student"

class subject(models.Model):
    sid=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sub=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cid=models.ForeignKey(course,to_field='cid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table= "subject"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sub
```

this is views.py

```
from .models import student
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    student_list=student.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('studinfo/index.html')
    context= { 'student_list' : student_list, }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def detail(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST['namedrop']
        idd=student.objects.all
        return render(request, 'studinfo/detail.html', {'name':name})
```

also i want it to display all the subjects that "neha" has through the details.html page...how do i do that?

Comment: please show the view that use the template too

Comment: views.py is already shown.

Comment: @Shefali It was removed in the previous edit, I restored it

Comment: yeah thanks..@PauloAlmeida..any answers?

Comment: What is `idd=student.objects.all` used for in your detail view? Currently not being used?

Comment: yes not being used currently!

Answer (score 1):

In your index template you are passing the name in the form, and just use it in the view to pass it along to the detail template. You need to get the `student` object and pass it to the detail template, so you have accesss to all its fields. You could start by passing the id in the form, instead of the name:

```
{% for student in student_list %}
    <option value={{ student.id }}>{{ student.stuname }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the view you can do something like this (you would probably want to add more sanity checks, like making sure the student exists):

```
def detail(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        student_id = request.POST['namedrop']
        student_instance = student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        idd=student.objects.all
        return render(request, 'studinfo/detail.html', {'student': student_instance})
```

Now in the detail template you have access to the `student` object and can use all its attributes (e.g. `{{ student.stuname }}`).

Since there is no direct connection between students and subjects, you have to go through the course:

```
{% for subject in student.cid.subject_set.all %}
    {{ subject }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yeah it worked..but how do i display all the subjects of a student?

Comment: @Shefali Loop through `{{ student.cid.subject_set.all }}`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida you know you just made my day..thanks..!!

Comment: @Shefali No problem, glad you got it working. In fact, many different people helped on several questions.

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the student with the following query in your view `detail`:

```
student = student.objects.filter(stuname=name)[0]
```

and add the result to the context :

```
return render(request, 'studinfo/detail.html', {'name':name, 'student': student})
```

Then in your template, you can call

```
{{student.stuname}} or {{student.cid}} ...
```

Comment: I was going to point out that `stuname` is not unique, but that's a good point. In the form drop down there will also be no way of discerning between students with the same name.