# How to pass pk from ModelForm to DetailView?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using `ClassroomCreateView` to choose a Classroom.  I then want to display the classroom chosen using `ClassroomDetailView`.  This will show a list of students in that classroom.  I think I should be able to use the pk and traverse from the ModelForm to DetailView.

Classroom Model

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    BLOCK_NUMBER = (
        ('11', 'Block 1-1'),
        ('12', 'Block 1-2'),
        ('13', 'Block 1-3'),
        ('14', 'Block 1-4'),
        ('21', 'Block 2-1'),
        ('22', 'Block 2-2'),
        ('23', 'Block 2-3'),
        ('24', 'Block 2-4'),
    )
    class_list = models.TextField()
    course_block = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BLOCK_NUMBER)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_course_block_display()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Classroom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # overrides the default save function to parse the class list
        studentList = []
        studentList = self.class_list.split('\n')
        print (studentList)
        for line in studentList:
            line = line.strip('\r')
            s = Student.objects.create(nickname = line, classroom = self)
```

Student Model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(default='JohnS', max_length=31)
```

Forms.py

```
class AttendForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        fields = ['course_block']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttendForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Views.py

```
class AttendCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Classroom
    form_class = AttendForm
    template_name = 'classroom/attend_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('classroom:random', self.kwargs['pk'])

create_attendance_view = AttendCreateView.as_view()
```

This is the part that I'm missing I think. `course_block` has a pk but I'm not passing it along from the form to the view.

```
class ClassroomDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Classroom
    template_name = 'classroom/random_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        class_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        context = super(ClassroomDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        students = Student.objects.filter(pk = 'class_pk')
        context['students'] = students
        return context

detail_classroom_view = ClassroomDetailView.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^classup/$', create_classroom_view, name='classroom'),
url(r'^attend/$', create_attendance_view, name='students'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', detail_classroom_view, name='random'),
```

How can I go from my form choice to detail view (probably using pk of the choice)?

Comment: Show your `urls.py`, namely what `classroom:random` is. Also, what is happening? Do you get an error, a wrong link in the template, something else?

Comment: Edited above to show urls.py.  When I used the self.object.id, after submitting the AttendForm on AttendCreateView, the id# in the ClassroomDetailView would just autoincrement. ie .../45/ then /46/ etc.  I had a print statement in ClassroomDetailView to print self.kwargs['pk'] and it would print "none." There aren't any errors.

Comment: Ok, only now I understood what you want to do. It's actually very similar to [a previous question on Stack Overflow today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699023/displaying-other-attribute-values-if-one-is-known-in-django-template/45699325), but she was using a function-based view (`index`) where you are attempting to use `CreateView`. I agree with your comment to the answer, if I were to use a class-based view for that I would go with a [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).

Comment: On the FormView you can just override `form_valid`, process the form to get the `pk` of the selected classroom and redirect to `detail_classroom_view` with the appropriate `pk` (as you are doing in `get_success_url` now).

Comment: I added the `__init__` to `AttendForm` and I changed the `CreateView` to a `FormView`.  I can't figure out how to process the form to get the `pk` though.

Comment: The `__init__` in `AttendForm` isn't doing anything, but that form was one thing that puzzled me. You want to list all classrooms, right? You can't do that with a ModelForm for classroom, which will list the fields of one classroom. You could use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), with a queryset of `Clasroom.objects.all()`, or just make the form manually in HTML, like in the question I linked to. Then you process that form in `form_valid` and redirect to the appropriate classroom.

Comment: I'll try making my own form, the link is very useful to me thanks. My ModelForm does list all classrooms, the field gets treated as a `ModelChoiceField` FWIW, perhaps not in a way that is useful to me though. I think I now see how to get the id using a my own manual form. The class based things in Django are helpful but the extra levels of abstraction hide some of things I need to learn.

Comment: You mean that `AttendForm` as you posted it is listing all classrooms? `course_block` is its only field. Class-based or function-based views are a matter of preference, if you like functions better go for it.

Comment: Yes, I only have 8 classrooms though, corresponding to the 8 choices of `course_block`.